# Mixpanel: Can an event map to two different profiles

Tags: mixpanel

I have an event which is linked to two different profiles. I want it to be visible in both the profiles.

For eg.

Profile A: distinct_id -> 123
Profile B: distinct_id -> ABC

Event E: distinct_id -> ? (should this be the alias, not sure)

Is it possible in MIXPANEL?

Comment: I donot think you can do that. Mixpanel keeps track of every event in single profile for that distinct id.

Comment: Thanks @PrajwalBati I agree. The use case I am working on is not suitable for MixPanel.